# Having the roots of a polynomial, is it possible to go back and find a polynomial that have exactly these roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

This might be very silly. But I've been wondering if it's possible to assume $n$ numbers as roots of $p(x)$ and find a polynomial that have these roots. I've made a table with some polynomials $ax^2+bx+c$ where the first column are the coefficients $(a,b,c)$ and it's roots on second and third column, but I couldn't notice any helpful patterns:

> $\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $ [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the polynomial under study is monic of degree $n$, and attains exactly $n$ roots say $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$, then we can write it as:

$$(x-\alpha_1) \times \cdots \times (x - \alpha_n)$$

Thus obtaining its expression.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $a$ is a root of polynomial $p(x)$, then $(x-a)$ divides $p(x)$, therefore $p(x)=(x-a)*q(x)$, apply it once more on $q(x)$. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just from reversing the quadratic formula, you can find a polynomial for any root of the form $q + r\sqrt{s}$.  If you want the radical multiplied by $i$, just move it under the radical since $q + ri\sqrt{s} = q + r\sqrt{-s}$.

Let $b = -2q$, and $c =  q^2 - sr^2$

Then using the quadratic formula on $x^2 + bx + c$, you get:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} & = \frac{2q\pm \sqrt{\left(2q\right)^2-4\cdot 1 \cdot(q^2-sr^2)}}{2\cdot 1}\\
& = q \pm \sqrt{q^2 + sr^2 - q^2} \\
& = q \pm \sqrt{sr^2} \\
& = q \pm r \sqrt{s}\\
\end{align}$$